# What does 'git log branchA branchB' do?

Tags: git

I saw a screencast where Gary Bernhardt ran `git log master origin/master` and I can't figure out what that does. What does `log` do when given two branches like that? I've used it in the past to show the commits that are on development and not yet on master (`git log development ^master`), and given it a range of revisions (`git log oldref..newref`), but this appears to be something different.

I don't see any mention in the docs either. Any help?

Comment: The man page says to go read git-rev-list. Did you read that? It is explained there.

Comment: @mikez I missed that. It makes a lot more sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
git log <ref1> <ref2>
```

prints log entries for all commits that are in the *union* of `<ref1>`'s ancestry and `<ref2>`'s ancestry; in other words, all the commits that are reachable *either from `<ref1>` or `<ref2>` or both*.

This syntax naturally extends to more than two revisions.

### Where to find that information in the man pages

Look up the *Description* section in the `git-log` man page:

> The command takes options applicable to the `git rev-list` command to
>   control what is shown and how [...]

This leads you to `git-rev-list` man page. Under the *Description* section of the latter, you'll find the following passage, which should clear things up:

> **List commits that are reachable by following the parent links from the
>   given commit(s)**, but exclude commits that are reachable from the
>   one(s) given with a `^` in front of them. The output is given in reverse
>   chronological order by default.
>
> You can **think of this as a set operation**. Commits given on the command
>   line form a set of commits that are reachable from any of them, and
>   then commits reachable from any of the ones given with `^` in front
>   are subtracted from that set. The remaining commits are what comes out
>   in the command's output. [...]

(my emphasis)

So there you have it: when you pass a (space-separated) list of references to `git log`, you get a log of all the commits that are reachable from at least one of the specified references.

### An example

As an example (taken from the [gitrevisons man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)), if your repo looks as follows

```
   J
    \
I -- F -- C 
      \    \
  E -- B -- A
      /
H -- D
    /
   G
```

the output of

```
git log D F
```

will contain log entries for all the commits that are reachable from commits `D` or `F` or both, i.e. commits `G`, `H`, `I`, `J`, `D`, and `F`.

Answer (score 3):

See **SPECIFYING RANGES** in [`git-rev-parse(1)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html). Basically, you're specifying a set of commits using any number of positive references, negative references, and ranges.